# Can i work as beta tester for Ubuntu phone and tablets?

Tags: beta

I am passionate about ubuntu OS and would like to use as most i can.
and its proud to be working as beta tester for ubuntu.
Please let me know how can i be part of ubuntu.
i am software developer by profession and very well aware with the testing and development methodology.

Thanks,
Abhishek Tiwari
India

Comment: Take a look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam?action=show&redirect=Testing

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the best would be to join the ubuntu phone mailing list.
It should be accessible [here](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/).